# Using Android GraphView in a Custom built dialog in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-graphview

I am trying to add a GraphView to my custom built dialog popup, but I am getting a NullPointerException every time.

I have tested both the GraphView and Dialog popup seperately, so I know that both of them are correct. I just can't implement the GraphView in the dialog.
As stated in the headline, all of this is located in a fragment,

Så here is the code for the dialog and graphview:

```
public void showStatisticWindow(Exercise exercise, ViewGroup cont) {
// Get the graph
GraphView graph = (GraphView) v.findViewById(R.id.graph_exercise_statistic);

BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
        new DataPoint(0, -2),
        new DataPoint(1, 5),
        new DataPoint(2, 3),
        new DataPoint(3, 2),
        new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);

// Create the dialog / popup
final View popupExerciseStatisticView = View.inflate(cont.getContext(), R.layout.popup_statistic_exercise, null);
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cont.getContext());
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.setTitle("Create the program");
alert.setView(popupExerciseStatisticView);
builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alert.dismiss();
    } });
alert.show();

}
```

And here is the xml layout for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/popup_statistic_exercise">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/graph_exercise_statistic" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/graph_relativelayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sets"
            android:id="@+id/sets_names_headline"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sets_names_headline"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sets_names_headline"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sets_names_headline"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/sets_names_list"></LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly, here is the output from the console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mobileplatformexam.fragments.StatisticExercisesFragment.showStatisticWindow(StatisticExercisesFragment.java:153)
            at com.mobileplatformexam.fragments.StatisticExercisesFragment$1.onTouch(StatisticExercisesFragment.java:87)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2038)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1396)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2535)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1986)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5738)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2900)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:849)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code on line 153 is:

```
 graph.addSeries(series);
```

I hope that someone have any idea on what could be wrong. If more information are needed, just ask.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the code in line 153

Comment: when was `v` was initialized?

Comment: in onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState), which calls the method in my question. But I can easily make a custom dialog, without the graphview. It is when I add it to the dialog things go wrong.

Comment: you cant add graph view like this in dialog, rather add a graphview in custom dialog layout and render it while showing dialog.

Comment: hmm okay how can I do that ? Not an expert on Android obviously

Answer (score 1):

It's been about 1 year since the question is asked, but I'll just leave my answer in case anyone need it.

According to your xml file, the `GraphView` element that you want is an element of the `popup_statistic_exercise` layout. So, you need to get the `GraphView` object after your inflate the `View` of the dialog that uses the `popup_statistic_exercise` layout.

```
// Create the dialog / popup
final View popupExerciseStatisticView = View.inflate(cont.getContext(), R.layout.popup_statistic_exercise, null);

// Get the graph
GraphView graph = (GraphView) popupExerciseStatisticView.findViewById(R.id.graph_exercise_statistic);

BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
        new DataPoint(0, -2),
        new DataPoint(1, 5),
        new DataPoint(2, 3),
        new DataPoint(3, 2),
        new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);

final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cont.getContext());
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.setTitle("Create the program");
alert.setView(popupExerciseStatisticView);
builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alert.dismiss();
    } });
alert.show();
```